# WiFi device having Bridge with AP Mode

Tags: wifi, networking, access-point

My root WiFi access point has WPA2-PSK(AES/TKIP) security. I want to extend it with different SSID and passphrase.

I found TP-Link devices at affordable price such as, [WA-701ND V1](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-12_TL-WA701ND.html), [TL-WR702N](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR702N.html) but I guess they do not support root access point with WPA2-PSK security.
I have requirement like [this](http://www.tp-link.in/FAQ-835.html) but TL-WA701ND V2 is currently not available in India.

Recommend me such hardware of any brand available at online shopping portals.

Comment: What's the make and model of the Wifi router you have now?

Comment: Currently Linksys WRT54G, and D-Link DAP-1360 are root APs. However I wish not to stick with them always. In future I may buy new AP, or use android hotspot capability.

Comment: I achieved it using TP Link Nano Router.